# How to access Oracle table stats, specifically NUM_ROWS and AVG_ROW_LEN, using JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, statistics

Is there a way to access Oracle table level statistics in a Java application using JDBC? I'm specifically interested in values NUM_ROWS and AVG_ROW_LEN for the purpose of estimating optimal memory buffer size and fetch size for my queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not concerned with database independence

```
SELECT num_rows, avg_row_len
  FROM all_tables
 WHERE owner = '<<owner of the table>>'
   AND table_name = '<<name of the table>>'
```

Comment: Do I need special permissions to run this query? The account my application is using has enough permissions to read/update/delete data in the tables in question and to run DDL.

Comment: @Olaf - You shouldn't.  Everyone should have access to the `ALL_TABLES` view which shows you information about all the tables that you have access to.  If you were trying to get statistics for tables that you didn't have access to `SELECT` from, you'd need access to the `DBA_TABLES` view which would likely require additional privileges.